# Ladybug Camera Driver

Tags: ros, camera-driver, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a Point Grey Ladybug camera around?

I am aware that the "pan" command from the IEEE1394 protocol can be used to access the individual cameras but when moving at high velocities there will be a large displacement between the images grabbed. It is necessary to command the camera to grab all the images first before transferring them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9602/ladybug-camera-driver/) by [Navid Nourani](https://answers.ros.org/users/364/navid-nourani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2017-11-20**:
I am using the Camera1394 driver for Ladybug camera. How are you changing the pan for different frames runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not aware of any reports of using the Ladybug with [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394). It is not included in the [list of cameras tested](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/CameraList).

That driver currently does not support the IIDC Pan feature. A patch to support it should be simple, and could be officially supported in the next release, if you need it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-07-16**:
according to the commit log in the camera1394 stack, this was added recently. Also someone called jep says he tested it on ladybug3 (which is what I have). I'd really like to get in touch with him. Also joq it'd be great if you could give a more updated answer to the question. thanks

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-10-02**:
For the record: after discussion it appears that the Ladybug 3 differs too much from the IIDC standard ton include in the basic 1394 driver. Brice is developing a device specific fork to handle that device. https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/issues/17 is the issue.